# AddThis: og:image not properly used until second attempt to share

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, addthis

URL: http://comicskingdom.com/arctic-circle/2014-05-27

Click the facebook share button once. It ignores the og:image I have set. Close the dialog, click share again, and it will use the image properly.

Debugger at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ shows the correct og:image, but on the first load it does not include that image in the list of available thumbnails.

If you run the test again, it will correctly use the og:image as the sharing thumbnail.

I don't know the first question to ask about this problem - could facebook be caching something? The og:image is URL shortened via bit.ly, if that could matter.

Thanks in advance to anyone who has some insight into this!

Comment: It work's on first attempt

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you end up solving it?